# How to prevent dropped connections in Firefox with a slow bandwidth?

Tags: firefox, internet

Whenever I'm downloading something with Firefox or other application and I try to access some website I get "server not found" response, which caused I'm sure because all of my limited bandwidth is being used by another process.

Is there a way to better distribute limited DSL bandwidth?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because your DNS servers are unresponsive. Try changing your DNS servers to the Google public ones, 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.

---

I used to experience this problem sometimes when I was using a 56K modem (which is very slow). I didn't know how to fix it then, but now I know about QoS. It is theoretically possible to use a router to give higher priority to DNS packets (this is known as Quality of Service, QoS for short). However if the problem is actually poor QoS from upstream, i.e. the ISP, there is probably nothing much you can do, other than, as you say, avoiding doing other things with the other internet connection at the same time. Torrents are particularly bad because they can use a lot of simultaneous connections. Of course you could try asking your ISP.